# Minimal Apple TV Setup

Tags: appletv, network, airplay, television

For an exhibition I need a minimal Apple TV setup that enables me to connect an iPad to an Apple TV via Air Play.

→ Ideally I **don't want to bring an extra router or computer**. Is it possible to connect the iPad to the Apple TV directly without having both joined to a wifi network?

If this is not the case, what would be an easy to setup solution for this? (Is it e.g. a separate Airport Express to create the network?)

Answer (score 1):

I just called Apple to make sure. The answer is unfortunately as expected:

- No, Apple TV and iPad cannot connect *directly* without being part of the same network.
- And yes, the best way to create this kind of network would be an Airport Express.

Well.